# question about the book "Holomorphic Morse Inequalities" by Marinescu-Ma

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, heat-equation

Could somebody please explain to me the proof of proposition 1.6.4 (page 52) in the book "Holomorphic Morse Inequalities" by Marinescu-Ma? I am completely lost. One point that is really confusing to me is the powers of p on the right hand side of the inequality (1.6.15).

Thanks

Andres